# Converting density=mass/volume to relative rate equation for integration

Tags: differentiation, integration, density

In order to get the mass of an object from density, we might use
\begin{equation}
 m = \int\rho(x)dx \tag{1}
\end{equation}

I understand why this works on a conceptual level, but I would like to be able to derive this equation from

\begin{align}
 m = \rho x \tag{2}
\end{align}

If I differentiate both sides, I get

$$ dm = \rho(x)dx + d\rho(x)x = \rho(x)dx + \rho'(x)xdx$$

Evidently, I want just the first term on the RHS, which means starting from (2) and differentiating doesn't work for deriving  (1). Is this because $\rho$ functions as an average value in (2) and therefore we cannot differentiate like we would normally? i.e.

$$\rho = \frac{\int\rho(x)dx}{\int dx}$$

such that

$$m = \rho x = \int\rho(x)dx$$

I would also like to compare this to a similar treatment of momentum $p = mv$, where $dp = vdm + mdv$. To my understanding this is correct. Does this work because we are not referring to an average variable but a scalar quantity tied to a moving object? Following, does the above treatment of differentiating an equation to get a relative rate equation work, given that none of the variables are averages?

Comment: *I would like to be able to derive this equation from $m=\rho x$* why?

Answer (score 1):

While the definition of momentum is: $p = mv,\;$ the definition of $\rho$ = $dm/dx$, $m$ being a function of x.
$\rho = m/x$ only if it is constant along the axis.

So, it is not correct to write $m = \rho x$ in general.